# Pentaho Data Integration with Hive connection

Tags: hadoop, hive, pentaho, data-integration

I am using **Pentaho Data Integration** and I am trying to connect to **Hive** but when i am trying to do so, i am getting below error.....

```
Error connecting to database [Hive] : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error occured while trying to connect to the database

Error connecting to database: (using class org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver)
org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException


org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error occured while trying to connect to the database

Error connecting to database: (using class org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver)
org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException    
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.normalConnect(Database.java:428)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:361)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:314)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:302)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.DatabaseFactory.getConnectionTestReport(DatabaseFactory.java:80)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.DatabaseMeta.testConnection(DatabaseMeta.java:2685)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.core.database.dialog.DatabaseDialog.test(DatabaseDialog.java:109)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.core.database.wizard.CreateDatabaseWizardPage2.test(CreateDatabaseWizardPage2.java:157)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.core.database.wizard.CreateDatabaseWizardPage2$3.widgetSelected(CreateDatabaseWizardPage2.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:820)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:796)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.core.database.wizard.CreateDatabaseWizard.createAndRunDatabaseWizard(CreateDatabaseWizard.java:111)
```

using settings as localhost, port as 8888 and database as default....

Kindly help, awaiting for your reply....

Regards,
Jiten Pansara

Answer (score 0):

What Hadoop distribution are you using? If you are not using Apache Hadoop 0.20.x, then you will have to configure PDI by setting certain properties, see the following Wiki page for more details on how to set up Pentaho for a particular Hadoop distribution:

http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/BAD/Configuring+Pentaho+for+your+Hadoop+Distro+and+Version

Answer (score 0):

Did you edit plugin.properties in the plugin folder??

> data-integration > plugins > pentaho-big-data-plugin > plugin.properties

change the property "active.hadoop.configuration" to the hadoop distribution you are using, eg :

> active.hadoop.configuration=hdp20

This might solve the issue.